# 1 new pluralization bugs in chat

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, tooltips, plurals

In the [list of chatrooms](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/), if there is one user present in a room, then it shows "1 users present" in the tooltip, not "1 user present":

[image: Pluralization bug]

Comment: I don't see such button, most likely it's a userscript you installed. In such case, it's a bug in the userscript itself, not in Stack Exchange code.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: That's a tooltip, not a button. I'll edit my question.

Comment: You can see the tooltip by hovering over the blank space near the list of users.

Comment: 1 new pluralization bug in your title: '1 new[...]bugs'

Comment: @Mhmd: That was intentional.

Comment: +1. Because it's totally obvious that this information is available by hovering the mouse cursor over that blank space. (No, not *that* blank space, the other blank space just above it.) How did nobody ever notice this before??? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tooltip and similar messages are now appropriately pluralized.

[image]